# Rewriting Subdomains to Subdirectory without redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to create virtual subdomains
like:

```
user1.domain.com/anythging >> domain.com/users/user1/anything
```

Without redirection

I use this cdoe in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectorySlash off
RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com.*$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/users/%1/$1 [P,L,NC,QSA]
```

But when I use :
    DirectorySlash off
I can rewrite: 
    user1.domain.com/anythging/ >> domain.com/users/user1/anything

with slash (/) at the end ( anythging/ ),
But this

```
user1.domain.com/anythging >> error 403: Forbidden
                              You don't have permission to access /users/user1/anythging on this server.
```

in the second case, when I use:

```
DirectorySlash ON
```

this:

```
user1.domain.com/anythging >> redirects to >> domain.com/users/user1/anythging
```

But I whant to rewrite the link not redirect it!

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectorySlash off
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://domain.com/users/%1/$1/ [P]
```

it might need some cleaning to redirect all www links to non-www and to exclude the www.domain.com from subdomain rewriting

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `DirectorySlash` isn't working for you but you don't exactly need it to achieve what you want. This `.htaccess` would also work. I'm assuming you want any trailing slash if present to be dropped.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://domain.com/users/%1/$1 [L]
```

Also, there's no need for proxy `[P]`, query string append `[QSA]` (it's on by default) and no-case `[NC]` (since, the rewrite regex only contains wildcards).

Comment: without the [P] , it wil redirect

Comment: Actually, with [R] it would redirect. With [P] you're invoking `mod_proxy`. More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).